# I cannot deploy my app on my phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, deployment

I've started yesterday afternoon studying WP7, so be patient.
I've just created my first test app, registered as developer on [AppHub](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/), connected my phone with Zune, registered my phone in my AppHub profile (I can see it in my devices section) and compiled my app.
When I try to transfer my app into phone (using Application Deployment Tool as described [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/pabloperalta/archive/2011/02/24/how-to-deploy-and-test-a-windows-phone-7-application-into-the-phone.aspx)) I get an error that can be traslated as 
Unable to connect to device because it's locked by pin

But my device has not any pin (or I don't know to have one) and it doesn't show anything on screen.
What could/should I do?

**UPDATE:**

- Zune is running: if I try I get the error
- I close Zune and run WPConnect: my device is connected but the error is the same

Comment: Is Zune running?  Also there is another tool for connecting its located in the same place as the app deploy tool, it's called WPConnect, I think.

Comment: To use WPConnect, start Zune, once it's running close it, then use WPConnect.

Comment: @DerekBeattie: yes, I did it exactly in the order you're telling me but it doesn't work, same error

Comment: Also make sure your device screen is unlocked

Comment: @nkchandra: that was the problem, I really cannot believe it!! Post it as an answer and I'll accept it. It's crazy...

Comment: Have you tried register, unregister, then register again?

Comment: Also, do you have sim card in it? Can you make a call?

Comment: @lukas: no, I don't have a SIM but that's not the problem; problem was that my phone screen was locked... I think this is crazy, but that's the reality...

Comment: @Marco sure! that's the proper way, right click on the project in Solution Explorer and Deploy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When deploying the app, make sure the phone screen is unlocked.

Additinal info: If you are developing from Desktop PC, sometimes connecting from front USB panel wont work.

Answer (score 2):

You can't deploy while the screen lock is active, so try swiping up the lock screen before deploying.